# I want to make animation in Inkcanvas control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I want to make animation in Inkcanvas control like draw stroke and stroke path so it can move over the stroke path how ?

Answer (score 0):

First grab the strokes from the InkCanvas.

Then get a GeometryPath from each stroke by calling GetGeometry() on the strokes.

After that you can [use the GeometryPath in a Path animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970561.aspx)

If you want to animate a pencil/brush along the stroke you'll need some extra calculations if you want to keep the pencil perpendicular (or at some angle) to the stroke.

Comment: Now I get MatrixAnimationusingpath like example and have the geometry of stroke that I want to animate the problem is that stroke doesn't have RenderTransfrom only has Transform properties and I don't know how can I use geometry with this matrix ?! please help thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimationusingpath.aspxthat might suit your needs better. there are many ...AnimationsUsingPath